# How to get the index value from html element?

Tags: c#, watin

I have a sample html :

```
<div class="linkWrap">
    <a href="http://google.com">Google</a>
    <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">Stackoverflow</a>
    <a href="http://wikipedia.org">Wikipedia</a>
</div>
```

I want to get index value of html element.

How do I get index value of html element? like jQuery's .index()

```
public int GetLinkIndex(string url)
{
    // return browser.Link(Find.ByUrl(url)).Index()
}
```

Thanks for reading.

---

I've tried. But look a little wrong..

```
public int GetLinkIndex(string url)
{
    if(browser.Link(Find.ByUrl(url)).Exists)
    {
        int i = 0;
        while(true)
        {
            string href = browser.Link(Find.BySelector(".linkWrap > a") && Find.ByIndex(i)).GetAttributeValue("href");
            if(href == url)
            {
                return i;
            }
            i += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In html, elements are static. Why don't use an ID for each element? I don't know if exists an index for the elements because a DIV isn't a list or any enumerable, is just a division inside your document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it for all the elements or only for specific elements type. As you mentioned in the sample code, it seems to be for Links. Then the following code would help you

```
public Int GetListIndex(string url)
{
   LinkCollection links = browser.Links;
   int count = -1;
   foreach(Link lnk in links)
   {
      if(lnk.GetAttributeValue("href").Contains(url))
      {
         return ++count;
      }
     count++;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to safe your html-file in an String-Array with this Stream reader function
msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/aa287535(v=vs.71).aspx

than you can deleate the first and the last row, with contains "" and ""

next you can use the trim Funktion to deleate the first 8 and the last 4 characters in every line. msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/d4tt83f9(v=vs.110).aspx

now you have an Array with entrys like ""http://google.com">Google". 
you can use the split-funktion to split the http-part, from the Name
msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx

store both parts in an 2-dimensional array. 
now you have an indexed array of your URLs